# SPARQL string RANGE

Tags: string, selection, sparql, region

I am trying to extract a part of a string by using index numbers.
When having

```
"OEIUFHWOIEFWNFOPQWJFHQWOIHFEB..."
```

and I need string from `5:10 (FHWOIE)` I found out that it is not possible via REGEX as that returns only boolean and not groups. However, I did not manage to find a region selection on strings via positions. Now I am wondering if there is any?

I found out that it is partly possible via...

```
BIND(REPLACE(?sequence, '^.{100}', "") AS ?sequencestrip1)
```

but not

```
BIND(REPLACE(?sequence, '^.{?start}', "") AS ?sequencestrip1)
```

I think this does it for anyone who is interested:

```
BIND(REPLACE(?sequence, "^.{"+str(?start)+"}", "") AS ?sequencestrip1)
```

and of course to remove the area behind what you are interested in

```
BIND(REPLACE(?region, ".{"+str(strlen(?region)-10)+"}$", "") AS ?upstream)
```

Comment: On StackOverflow, you can answer your own questions.  If you find a solution, you can post it as an answer.  This helps to make things clearer for anyone who arrives later.

Answer (score 5):

In the first [SPARQL Query Language for RDF](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/), this would be rather difficult, because there are not many string manipulation functions.  However, in your question, you've used [`replace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-replace) which appeared in [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/).  This is good for you because, in addition to `replace`, SPARQL 1.1 includes more string manipulation functions.  One of these, [`substr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-substr), does exactly what you need. For instance, here's a query in which `?string` is bound to the string you mentioned, and `substr` is used to extract the substring you're looking for and bind it as `?substring`.

```
select * where { 
  values ?string { "OEIUFHWOIEFWNFOPQWJFHQWOIHFEB..." }
  bind( substr( ?string, 5, 6 ) as ?substring )
}
```

The results are:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| string                             | substring |
==================================================
| "OEIUFHWOIEFWNFOPQWJFHQWOIHFEB..." | "FHWOIE"  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Note that the second argument to `substr` is the starting position (where the first index is 1), and the third is the *length* of the substring, not the final position.  You wanted a substring, `FHWOIE`, that has six characters, to the third argument is 6.